# how to handle when my jsonarray value is null in android

Tags: android

how to handle these null in json array values

```
{
    "Code": "0",
    "Message": "Success",
    "District": null,
    "Division": null,
    "Circle": null,
    "PoliceStation": null,
    "Vehicle": [
        {
            "VehicleId": "81",
            "VehicleNo": "Srikakulam II Town - PV1 [AP18P1470]"
        },
        {
            "VehicleId": "82",
            "VehicleNo": "Srikakulam II Town - BC-I [AP18P2325]"
        },
        {
            "VehicleId": "83",
            "VehicleNo": "Srikakulam II Town - BC-II [AP18P2326]"
        },
        {
            "VehicleId": "89",
            "VehicleNo": "Srikakulam II Town - PV2 [AP18P3244]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: use `optString()` instead of `getString()`

Comment: use your imagination

Comment: am using optString()

Comment: check !=null for all parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.isNull()` method to check weather the item is null or not

> **[isNull](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29)**
> added in API level 1
>
> `boolean isNull (String name)`
>
> Returns true if this object has no mapping for name or if it has a mapping whose value is NULL.

**sample code**

```
if(!object.isNull("District")) {
    //District value is not null
}
```

Comment: its wrkng tq @Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

Please used below answer your questions:

`private String optString_1(final JSONObject json, final String key) {
        return json.isNull(key) ? null : json.optString(key);
    }`